# Getting data for multiple products using a single scraper

Tags: python, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

I have the link https://www.1800wheelchair.com/category/369/transport-wheelchairs/ from which I want to extract table data for all products (specifications). I could write the code for a single product as below. The issue arises when I try to run this in a loop for multiple products. How can I obtain 1 single excel file that includes row wise entries for each product?

```
import csv
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup


def single(page_link):
    

    headers = {'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Ubuntu; Linux x86_64; rv:78.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/78.0'}
    soup = BeautifulSoup(requests.get(page_link, headers=headers).content, 'html.parser')


    with open('output.csv', 'w', newline='') as f:
        writer = csv.writer(f)
        for items in soup.find('table').find_all('tr'):
            data = [item.get_text(strip=True) for item in items.find_all(['td'])]
            #print(data)
            writer.writerow(data)
            
def scraper(max_pages):
    page=1
    while (page<=max_pages):
        url= 'https://www.1800wheelchair.com/category/369/transport-wheelchairs/'
        headers = {'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Ubuntu; Linux x86_64; rv:78.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/78.0'}
        soup = BeautifulSoup(requests.get(url, headers=headers).content, 'html.parser')
        for link in soup.findAll("h2", {"class":"product-name"}):
            href=link.find("a")['href']
            title = link.string
            #worksheet.write(row_i, 0, title)
            single(href)
            print(href)
            #print(title)
        page+=1
scraper(3)
```

Comment: Can you share the code you tried for writing multiple products? Have you tried keeping the output.csv file opened and putting the "multiple products loop" inside that with block?

Comment: @MilanCermak i have updated the code. please check now. thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
import requests, json, time
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import pandas as pd

url = "https://www.1800wheelchair.com/category/369/transport-wheelchairs/?p="
headers = {'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Ubuntu; Linux x86_64; rv:78.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/78.0'}

data = []

for i in range(1,4):
    print(i)
    res = requests.get(url + str(i), headers=headers)
    soup = BeautifulSoup(res.text, "html.parser")
    p_links = [i["data-link"] for i in soup.find("ul", {"id":"products-list"}).find_all("li",class_=["openlink","item"])]

    for prod_url in p_links:
        print(prod_url)
        temp = {"Product URL": prod_url}
        prod_res = requests.get(prod_url, headers = headers)
        prod_soup = BeautifulSoup(prod_res.text, "html.parser")

        table = prod_soup.find("table",{"class":"specifications"})
        for tr in table.find_all("tr"):
            temp[tr.find("td", {"class":"tdLabel"}).text.strip()] = tr.find("td", {"class":"tdValue"}).text.strip()
        data.append(temp)
        time.sleep(1)

pd.DataFrame(data).to_csv("data.csv", index=False)

with open("data.json","w") as f:
    json.dump(data, f)
```

The code will save 2 files. One json and csv.

Output:

```
[{"Product URL": "https://www.1800wheelchair.com/product/featherweight-wheelchair/", "Weight Capacity": "220 lbs.", "Product Weight": "19 lbs.", "Weight Without Wheels": "13.5 lbs.", "Seat Width": "18\"", "Seat Depth": "16\"", "Seat-to-Floor Height": "17.5\"", "Overall Width": "27.5\"", "Overall Length": "30\"", "Overall Height": "35\"", "Folded Depth": "29\"", "Folded Height": "28\"", "Folded Width": "15\"", "Front Wheel Size": "6\"", "Rear Wheel Size": "22\"", "Axle Type": "Fixed, Quick Release", "Armrest Options": "Full Length", "Back Height": "16\"", "Upholstery Type": "Nylon", "Upholstery Color": "Gray, Red", "Footrests": "Swingaway", "Warranty on Frame": "Lifetime Limited", "Warranty on Wearable Parts": "Six Months Limited"}, {"Product URL": "https://www.1800wheelchair.com/product/probasics-steel-transport-wheelchair/", "Weight Capacity": "300 lbs.", "Product Weight": "25 lbs.", "Seat Width": "19\"", "Seat Depth": "16\"", "Seat-to-Floor Height": "19\"", "Overall Width": "21.25\"", "Overall Length": "26.75\", 38.75\"", "Overall Height": "37\"", "Folded Width": "9\"", "Frame Color": "Silver", "Front Wheel Size": "8\"", "Rear Wheel Size": "8\"", "Axle Type": "Fixed", "Armrest Options": "Full Length", "Back Height": "16\"", "Upholstery Type": "Nylon", "Upholstery Color": "Black", "Footrests": "Swingaway", "HCPCS": "E1038", "Warranty on Frame": "Lifetime Limited", "Warranty on Wearable Parts": "One Year Limited", "Shipping Weight": "34 lbs.", "Box Length": "23\"", "Box Width": "11\"", "Box Height": "31\""}, {"Product URL": "https://www.1800wheelchair.com/product/excel-freedom-transport-chair/", "Weight Capacity": "300 lbs.", "Product Weight": "15 lbs.", "Seat Width": "19\"", "Seat Depth": "16\"", "Seat-to-Floor Height": "19.5\"", "Overall Width": "24.5\"", "Overall Length": "25\"", "Overall Height": "37.5\"", "Folded Width": "8\"", "Frame Color": "Black - Red", "Front Wheel Size": "6\"", "Rear Wheel Size": "8\"", "Axle Type": "Fixed", "Armrest Options": "Desk Length", "Back Height": "19\"", "Upholstery Type": "Nylon", "Upholstery Color": "Black", "Footrests": "Swingaway", "HCPCS": "E1038", "Is Latex Free": "Yes", "Warranty on Frame": "Lifetime Limited", "Warranty on Wearable Parts": "One Year Limited", "Shipping Weight": "23 lbs., 23.3 lbs.", "Box Length": "23\" - 24.5\"", "Box Width": "9.1\" - 9.5\"", "Box Height": "31.5\" - 32.5\""}, {"Product URL": "https://www.1800wheelchair.com/product/rollz-rollator-transport-chair-in-one/", "Weight Capacity": "275 lbs.", "Product Weight": "23.7 lbs., 31.8 lbs.", "Seat Width": "16.5\"", "Seat Depth": "8\", 15\"", "Seat-to-Floor Height": "19.5\", 21.5\"", "Overall Width": "25.5\"", "Overall Length": "24.8\"", "Folded Depth": "11.5\"", "Max. Handle Height": "37\", 39\"", "Min. Handle Height": "32\", 34\"", "Frame Color": "Black - White", "Number of Wheels": "4", "Front Wheel Size": "8\"", "Rear Wheel Size": "12\"", "Warranty on Frame": "Lifetime Limited", "Warranty on Wearable Parts": "Two Year Limited", "Shipping Weight": "8.16 lbs"}, {"Product URL": "https://www.1800wheelchair.com/product/karman-s-115-ergonomic-transport-chair/", "Weight Capacity": "250 lbs.", "Product Weight": "22 lbs.", "Seat Width": "16\" - 20\"", "Seat Depth": "17\"", "Seat-to-Floor Height": "19\"", "Overall Width": "22\" - 25\"", "Overall Length": "36\"", "Overall Height": "36\"", "Folded Width": "12\"", "Frame Color": "Silver", "Front Wheel Size": "7\"", "Rear Wheel Size": "14\"", "Axle Type": "Fixed", "Armrest Options": "Full Length, Desk Length", "Back Height": "16\"", "Upholstery Type": "Nylon", "Upholstery Color": "Black, Gray", "Footrests": "Swingaway, Elevating", "HCPCS": "E1038", "Warranty on Frame": "One Year Limited", "Shipping Weight": "29 lbs.", "Box Length": "33\"", "Box Width": "13\"", "Box Height": "31\""}, {"Product URL": "https://www.1800wheelchair.com/product/expedition-lightweight-12-rear-wheel-transport-chair/", "Weight Capacity": "300 lbs.", "Product Weight": "19 lbs.", "Seat Width": "19\"", "Seat Depth": "16\"", "Seat-to-Floor Height": "19\"", "Overall Width": "22\"", "Overall Length": "38\"", "Overall Height": "38\"", "Folded Depth": "38\"", "Folded Width": "10.75\"", "Frame Color": "Blue, Red", "Front Wheel Size": "8\"", "Rear Wheel Size": "12\"", "Non-Marking Wheels": "Yes", "Axle Type": "Fixed", "Armrest Options": "Full Length", "Back Height": "18\"", "Upholstery Type": "Nylon", "Upholstery Color": "Black", "Footrests": "Swingaway", "Is Latex Free": "Yes", "Warranty on Frame": "Lifetime Limited", "Shipping Weight": "24 lbs.", "Box Length": "25\"", "Box Width": "10\"", "Box Height": "31\""}, {"Product URL": "https://www.1800wheelchair.com/product/travelite-transport-chair-with-bag/", "Weight Capacity": "250 lbs.", "Product Weight": "20.5 lbs.", "Seat Width": "18\"", "Seat Depth": "18\"", "Seat-to-Floor Height": "19\"", "Overall Width": "22.5\"", "Overall Length": "33\"", "Overall Height": "37.5\"", "Folded Width": "11.5\"", "Front Wheel Size": "8\"", "Rear Wheel Size": "8\"", "Non-Marking Wheels": "Yes", "Axle Type": "Fixed", "Armrest Options": "Desk Length, Flip Back", "Back Height": "17.5\"", "Upholstery Type": "Nylon", "Upholstery Color": "Black", "Footrests": "Swingaway", "Is Latex Free": "Yes", "Warranty on Frame": "Lifetime Limited", "Warranty on Wearable Parts": "Two Months Limited", "Shipping Weight": "23.2 lbs."}, {"Product URL": "https://www.1800wheelchair.com/product/strongback-ergonomic-curved-back-wheelchair/", "Weight Capacity": "300 lbs.", "Product Weight": "19.8 lbs., 22 lbs.", "Seat Width": "16\" - 20\"", "Seat Depth": "18\"", "Seat-to-Floor Height": "20\"", "Overall Width": "22.5\" - 28.5\"", "Overall Length": "41\"", "Overall Height": "36\"", "Folded Depth": "23\", 25\"", "Folded Height": "29.5\", 32\"", "Folded Width": "12\", 14\"", "Frame Color": "Blue", "Front Wheel Size": "6\"", "Rear Wheel Size": "8\", 12\"", "Axle Type": "Fixed", "Armrest Options": "Desk Length", "Back Height": "18.5\"", "Upholstery Type": "Nylon", "Upholstery Color": "Black", "Footrests": "Swingaway"}, {"Product URL": "https://www.1800wheelchair.com/product/karman-ergo-flight-transport-chair/", "Weight Capacity": "220 lbs.", "Product Weight": "18 lbs.", "Seat Width": "16\", 18\"", "Seat Depth": "17\"", "Seat-to-Floor Height": "18\"", "Overall Width": "23\", 25\"", "Overall Length": "36\"", "Overall Height": "36\"", "Folded Width": "12\"", "Frame Color": "Silver", "Front Wheel Size": "6\"", "Rear Wheel Size": "14\"", "Axle Type": "Fixed", "Armrest Options": "Desk Length", "Back Height": "17\"", "Footrests": "Swingaway", "HCPCS": "E1038", "Shipping Weight": "27 lbs.", "Box Length": "27\"", "Box Width": "12\"", "Box Height": "30\""}, {"Product URL": "https://www.1800wheelchair.com/product/probasics-lightweight-transport-chair/", "Weight Capacity": "300 lbs.", "Product Weight": "20 lbs.", "Seat Width": "19\"", "Seat Depth": "16\"", "Seat-to-Floor Height": "19\"", "Overall Width": "22\"", "Overall Length": "26.75\", 38.75\"", "Overall Height": "37\"", "Folded Width": "9\"", "Frame Color": "Blue - Red", "Front Wheel Size": "8\"", "Rear Wheel Size": "8\"", "Axle Type": "Fixed", "Armrest Options": "Full Length", "Back Height": "16\"", "Upholstery Type": "Nylon", "Upholstery Color": "Black", "Footrests": "Swingaway", "HCPCS": "E1038", "Warranty on Frame": "Lifetime Limited", "Warranty on Wearable Parts": "One Year Limited", "Shipping Weight": "26 lbs.", "Box Length": "23\"", "Box Width": "11\"", "Box Height": "31\""}, {"Product URL": "https://www.1800wheelchair.com/product/super-light-foldable-transport-chair-with-carry-bag/", "Weight Capacity": "250 lbs.", "Product Weight": "19 lbs.", "Seat Width": "18\"", "Seat Depth": "17\"", "Seat-to-Floor Height": "20\"", "Overall Width": "23\"", "Overall Length": "36\"", "Overall Height": "37\"", "Folded Width": "16\"", "Frame Color": "Silver", "Front Wheel Size": "6\"", "Rear Wheel Size": "8\"", "Non-Marking Wheels": "Yes", "Axle Type": "Fixed", "Armrest Options": "Desk Length, Flip Back", "Back Height": "17\"", "Upholstery Color": "Blue", "Footrests": "Swingaway", "HCPCS": "E1038", "Is Latex Free": "Yes", "Warranty on Frame": "Lifetime Limited", "Shipping Weight": "24 lbs."}, {"Product URL": "https://www.1800wheelchair.com/product/the-transformer-wheelchair/", "Weight Capacity": "250 lbs.", "Product Weight": "32 lbs. - 34 lbs.", "Weight Without Wheels": "21.6 lbs. - 23.8 lbs.", "Seat Width": "16\" - 20\"", "Seat Depth": "16\"", "Seat-to-Floor Height": "17\", 20\"", "Overall Width": "18\" - 29\"", "Overall Length": "28\" - 32\"", "Overall Height": "37\"", "Folded Width": "10\", 12\"", "Frame Color": "Black", "Front Wheel Size": "8\"", "Rear Wheel Size": "8\", 24\"", "Axle Type": "Quick Release", "Armrest Options": "Desk Length, Flip Back", "Back Height": "16\"", "Upholstery Type": "Nylon", "Upholstery Color": "Black", "Footrests": "Swingaway, Elevating", "HCPCS": "E0990 - K0195", "Warranty on Frame": "Lifetime Limited", "Warranty on Wearable Parts": "One Year Limited", "Shipping Weight": "35 lbs. - 37 lbs.", "Box Length": "33\"", "Box Width": "13\"", "Box Height": "37\""}, {"Product URL": "https://www.1800wheelchair.com/product/e-j-navigator-manual-transport-chair-in-one/", "Weight Capacity": "250 lbs.", "Product Weight": "33.5 lbs.", "Weight Without Wheels": "23 lbs.", "Seat Width": "18\"", "Seat Depth": "16\"", "Seat-to-Floor Height": "19.25\"", "Overall Width": "27.5\"", "Overall Length": "31\"", "Overall Height": "37.5\"", "Folded Width": "13.25", "Frame Color": "Red", "Front Wheel Size": "6\"", "Rear Wheel Size": "6\", 24\"", "Axle Type": "Quick Release", "Armrest Options": "Desk Length, Flip Back", "Back Height": "17.75\"", "Upholstery Type": "Nylon", "Upholstery Color": "Black", "Footrests": "Swingaway", "HCPCS": "K0003", "Warranty on Frame": "Two Year Limited"}, {"Product URL": "https://www.1800wheelchair.com/product/karman-s-ergo-lite-transport-chair/", "Weight Capacity": "220 lbs.", "Product Weight": "18 lbs.", "Seat Width": "16\", 18\"", "Seat Depth": "17\"", "Seat-to-Floor Height": "19\"", "Overall Width": "23\", 25\"", "Overall Length": "39\"", "Overall Height": "36\"", "Folded Width": "12\"", "Frame Color": "Silver", "Front Wheel Size": "6\"", "Rear Wheel Size": "14\"", "Axle Type": "Fixed", "Armrest Options": "Desk Length", "Back Height": "17\"", "Upholstery Type": "Nylon", "Upholstery Color": "Black, Gray", "Footrests": "Fixed", "HCPCS": "E1038", "Shipping Weight": "30 lbs.", "Box Length": "35\"", "Box Width": "12\"", "Box Height": "30\""}, {"Product URL": "https://www.1800wheelchair.com/product/drive-aluminum-transport-wheelchair/", "Weight Capacity": "300 lbs.", "Product Weight": "19 lbs.", "Seat Width": "17\", 19\"", "Seat Depth": "16\"", "Seat-to-Floor Height": "19\"", "Overall Width": "20\", 22\"", "Overall Length": "33\"", "Overall Height": "39.5\"", "Folded Width": "9\"", "Frame Color": "Black - Red", "Front Wheel Size": "8\"", "Rear Wheel Size": "8\"", "Non-Marking Wheels": "Yes", "Axle Type": "Fixed", "Armrest Options": "Full Length", "Back Height": "19\"", "Upholstery Type": "Nylon", "Upholstery Color": "Black", "Footrests": "Swingaway", "HCPCS": "E1038", "Is Latex Free": "Yes", "Warranty on Frame": "Lifetime Limited", "Shipping Weight": "24 lbs.", "Box Length": "25\"", "Box Width": "10\"", "Box Height": "31\""}, {"Product URL": "https://www.1800wheelchair.com/product/everest-jennings-aluminum-transport-chair/", "Weight Capacity": "250 lbs.", "Product Weight": "20 lbs.", "Seat Width": "17\", 19\"", "Seat Depth": "16\"", "Seat-to-Floor Height": "19.25\"", "Overall Width": "22.25\", 24.25\"", "Overall Length": "23\"", "Overall Height": "39.25\"", "Folded Width": "10.75\"", "Frame Color": "Blue - Silver", "Front Wheel Size": "8\"", "Rear Wheel Size": "8\"", "Axle Type": "Fixed", "Armrest Options": "Full Length", "Back Height": "18.5\"", "Upholstery Type": "Nylon", "Upholstery Color": "Black", "Footrests": "Swingaway", "HCPCS": "E1038", "Warranty on Frame": "One Year Limited", "Shipping Weight": "25 lbs.", "Box Length": "25\"", "Box Width": "10\"", "Box Height": "31\""}, {"Product URL": "https://www.1800wheelchair.com/product/probasics-aluminum-transport-chair-with-12-rear-wheels/", "Weight Capacity": "300 lbs.", "Product Weight": "20 lbs.", "Seat Width": "19\"", "Seat Depth": "16\"", "Seat-to-Floor Height": "19\"", "Overall Width": "21.5\"", "Overall Length": "27.5\", 39\"", "Overall Height": "37\"", "Folded Width": "10.25\"", "Rear Wheel Size": "12\"", "Axle Type": "Fixed", "Armrest Options": "Full Length", "Back Height": "16\"", "Upholstery Type": "Nylon", "Upholstery Color": "Black", "Footrests": "Swingaway", "HCPCS": "E1038", "Warranty on Frame": "Lifetime Limited", "Warranty on Wearable Parts": "One Year Limited", "Shipping Weight": "29.5 lbs.", "Box Length": "25\"", "Box Width": "11\"", "Box Height": "31\""}, {"Product URL": "https://www.1800wheelchair.com/product/karman-ultralightweight-transport-wheelchair/", "Weight Capacity": "250 lbs.", "Product Weight": "28 lbs.", "Seat Width": "16\", 18\"", "Seat Depth": "17\"", "Seat-to-Floor Height": "19\"", "Overall Width": "23\", 25\"", "Overall Length": "39\"", "Overall Height": "36\"", "Folded Width": "12\"", "Frame Color": "Silver", "Front Wheel Size": "7\"", "Rear Wheel Size": "24\"", "Axle Type": "Quick Release", "Back Height": "17\"", "Footrests": "Swingaway", "Shipping Weight": "32 lbs.", "Box Length": "32\"", "Box Width": "12\"", "Box Height": "32\""}, {"Product URL": "https://www.1800wheelchair.com/product/nissin-lightweight-travel-chair/", "Weight Capacity": "220 lbs.", "Product Weight": "13 lbs.", "Seat Width": "13\", 15\"", "Seat Depth": "13\"", "Seat-to-Floor Height": "19\"", "Overall Width": "15.75\"", "Overall Height": "33\"", "Folded Depth": "7.5\"", "Folded Height": "21\"", "Folded Width": "15.7\"", "Front Wheel Size": "3\"", "Rear Wheel Size": "5\"", "Axle Type": "Fixed", "Armrest Options": "Flip Back", "Back Height": "14\"", "Upholstery Type": "Nylon", "Upholstery Color": "Black", "Footrests": "Fixed", "Warranty on Frame": "Lifetime Limited", "Warranty on Wearable Parts": "One Year Limited"}, {"Product URL": "https://www.1800wheelchair.com/product/fly-lite-transport-chair/", "Weight Capacity": "300 lbs.", "Product Weight": "16.2 lbs., 18.9 lbs.", "Seat Width": "19\"", "Seat Depth": "15.5\"", "Seat-to-Floor Height": "18\"", "Overall Width": "22\"", "Overall Length": "33\"", "Overall Height": "36\"", "Folded Width": "9\"", "Frame Color": "Black, Blue", "Front Wheel Size": "6\"", "Rear Wheel Size": "8\"", "Non-Marking Wheels": "Yes", "Axle Type": "Fixed", "Armrest Options": "Desk Length", "Back Height": "18\"", "Upholstery Type": "Nylon", "Upholstery Color": "Black - Silver", "Footrests": "Swingaway", "HCPCS": "E1038", "Is Latex Free": "Yes", "Warranty on Frame": "Lifetime Limited", "Shipping Weight": "23.80 lbs."}]
```

Comment: I'll award a bounty to this answer myself for the effort!!! LOL

Comment: this is helpful indeed. However, there is a small trouble with the wya this gives the output. I wanted a single excel file with unique headers in the 1st row, and entries for each product corresponding to these headers in rows afterwards. On converting JSON to excel here, i get a very different output from expected